# Sql with php search in large table , trying to optimize request

Tags: php, sql, performance, optimization

I'm looking to optimize my search function. I got more than 100 000 data lines in my table_1.
Each time a user makes a search , i look at the result in my table_1.
It takes too much time, and i need to anticipate for the futur in order to access datas simply. Do i have to recreate new smaller tables ?

```
$sql = "SELECT id FROM table_1 WHERE username LIKE '%$search%' OR  record_data  LIKE '%$search%'";
```

Comment: [Full-text search](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fulltext-search.html) may help.

Comment: Are you using MySQL? And do you really need `LIKE` (especially for `username`)?

Comment: Add a tag for the dbms used. Different products have different solutions.

Comment: What does the execution plan of your query tell you about the problem? Also, this query looks vulnerable to SQL injection to me

Comment: It really depends on what you're using wildcard operators for. Perhaps the column have been redacted for the post, but `username LIKE '%$search%'` looks strange (in what context do you need to do substring matches for usernames?) and `record_data  LIKE '%$search%'` can be a free text search (looking for references to "kittens") or a kind of structured data search (looking for references to invoice ABC0000123). Each use case has different solutions.

Comment: ok, thanks for your reply. $search has been " cleaned " before launching the request. You can forget username , i use SQL yes. Each users  add records with incremented id each time. So if someone need to find at the beginning of the table (a specific record in a char text line), the request can take time.

Comment: What do you mean by "cleaned"? Also, please share the execution plan for the given query

Comment: htmlentities, remove slash, string length limit... special char removed... the querie count the number of occurences of a word  in the table i-e record_data row and show result as list with the while loop $result=$row["record_data"];  that's all.

Comment: So you're not searching for the string the user entered? That might lead to unexpected results. Properly preparing the query would be a better idea - especially if you do the same magic on inserting the data

Comment: it's only plain text, when a user enter a value, it's limited by default to avoid injection.

Comment: Here is picture to show how : https://i.imgur.com/FiIIqpD.jpg

Comment: Whatever that picture should tell us: add all deteils to your question by editing it, and share all details in text form, not hidden in images